# Access Denied with psftp

Tags: sftp, batch-processing

I have a command line script that calls psftp.exe and passes in a number of parameters.
Below is the line from the batch script that I am running:

```
psftp -P 122 abc123@ftp.test.com -pw password
```

(I am not passing in a file using -b yet as I want to see if I can connect first)

On running this batch script I get the following output:

```
using username "abc123"
access denied
```

When I run this script with the verbose flag enabled I get the following output:

```
Looking for host "abc123"
Connecting to "<IP>" port 122
Server Version: SSH-2.0
Using SSH protocol version 2
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.63
Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
Server Refused keyboard-interactive authentication
Sent Password
Password authentication Failed
Access Denied
```

I have tried to connect using the same credentials through file zilla and can connect fine. Seems to be failing when sending the username to the server in the first example but failing at the password step in the later example.

Im a bit lost on what to try next; Can anyone help with this?

appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. Turns out the issue was that the password I was using has a > character which in cmd is an escape character. Putting the password in quotes solved the issue.

Comment: Would be nice if you update your question to make it useful for others. Like rewording it to "How do I use password with > in psftp?"

Comment: But the error that is thrown is 'Access Denied'. For someone to search for 'How do I use password with > in psftp', would imply that they already know the reason for the error, which wasn't the case with me.